# gpg creation permission denied in creation of ssl certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, gnupg, permission-denied

Error:

```
[haproxy@asdghyuyhg pem]$ gpg --output ms-sample.gpg -c ms-sample.pem
gpg: directory `/home/haproxy/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/home/haproxy/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/haproxy/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/home/haproxy/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: can't create `ms-sample.gpg': Permission denied
gpg: symmetric encryption of `ms-sample.pem' failed: Permission denied
```

Comment: can someone know how to fix this error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSL certificates.

Comment: There is two ssl/tsl certificates required in microservice: a. jks and b. gpg

Comment: This is not programming or development and is not really about either gpg or ssl. The user you are logged in as (haproxy) doesn't have permission to create a file in the directory you are using, nor does the group (which we don't know). Using basic logic, possible solutions are: (1) change permission on the directory to allow this user (or group) to create the file; (2) create the file in a different directory where haproxy (or your group) does have permission; (3) change to a different userid (or put haxproxy in a group) that does have permission for this directory.